# Dual-booted Windows 10 and Linux Mint 19

Tags: linux, linux-mint, partition, windows, dual-boot

It's been a year since I dual-booted Windows 10 and Linux Mint 19. I haven't booted into my Windows since then. And I can't delete the Windows partition because I have all my movies and TV shows downloaded on that partition.

Is there any way to just delete the Windows OS from that partition and leave all the movies and TV shows alone?

Comment: That can be done but it would be far easier and less tedious to back up the data that you want to keep, delete the partition, create a new one, and then restore the data to it.

Comment: What do you want to achieve here? Do you want to remove the partition itself so you can re-use the space? Do you want to keep the partition but delete some files from it to make some more space? Do you just want to remove Windows from your system and don't care about the space?

Comment: What @NasirRiley suggest also gives you the possibility to move away from an ntfs partition. In your shoes, I would probably want that.